# awk: line 1: syntax error at or near ,

Tags: dpkg, awk

I try to use the awk command on my file in dpkg and I get that error:

```
awk  '{print $1,$6}' cmd.txt > cmd2.txt
```

File content:

```
Port         Protocol Type              Board Name                FQBN             Core       
/dev/ttyACM0 serial   Serial Port (USB) Unknown                                               
/dev/ttyACM1 serial   Serial Port (USB) Arduino Mega or Mega 2560 arduino:avr:mega arduino:avr
/dev/ttyAMA0 serial   Serial Port       Unknown                                               
/dev/ttyAMA1 serial   Serial Port       Unknown                                               
/dev/ttyAMA2 serial   Serial Port       Unknown                                               
/dev/ttyAMA3 serial   Serial Port       Unknown                                               
/dev/ttyS0   serial   Serial Port       Unknown                                               
/dev/ttyUSB0 serial   Serial Port (USB) Unknown                                               
/dev/ttyUSB1 serial   Serial Port (USB) Unknown                                               
/dev/ttyUSB2 serial   Serial Port (USB) Unknown                                               
/dev/ttyUSB3 serial   Serial Port (USB) Unknown
```

It seems in dpkg, there are different behaviors. Can someone give me an advice.

Edit: My ideal case

```
arduino-cli board list | awk -F ' ' '{print $1,$6}' |while read var1 var2
do
  if [ "$var2" == "Arduino" ];then
      device_path=$var1
      dosomething...
      break;
  fi
done
```

Comment: What do you mean by "use the awk command on my file in dpkg"? Do you mean  you're running this in *Debian*?

Comment: I suspect this is a quoting issue and you are doing something equivalent to `sh -c "awk '{print $1,$6}' cmd.txt"` - in which `$1` and `$6` are unintentionally being expanded by the shell

Comment: @muru dpkg is used by Ubuntu as well. And it seems that this user is packaging a `.deb` package (from another question).

Comment: @Esther interesting. OP: please clarify where exactly you're running this script (if from a Debian postinst script, then a) show us the actual script, and (b) which OS you're installing this package in)

Comment: Awk works with record delimiters (i.e. space, coma, semicolon...). Your input file is not with delimiters, is presented as columns formatting. And unfortunately, some data columns (3 and 4) contain spaces.

Comment: Again: which OS are you running this on? Please post a command where the error is reproducible, not some "ideal" case.

Comment: I strongly agree with @muru ... you are not helping us help you ... Sorry for saying it frankly but, although we want to help you, we will not tolerate you ignoring community members asking for supporting information ... Do you enjoy making us guess what might work for you in a `while true; do ...; done` loop?  :-)

Comment: @muru I try to use awk in my dpkg but it seems there is wrong behaviors. I run the same command outside the dpkg it works properly but inside the command send me a empty result

Comment: @user3262532 that is not what I asked.

Comment: @muru I mean to use it in a postinst script of my dpkg file

Comment: Again, not what I asked.

Comment: @muru I try to run the code I post on my edit part on debian, on ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

Awk works with record delimiters (i.e. space, coma, semicolon...). Your input file is not with delimiters, is presented as columns formatting. And unfortunately, some data columns (3 and 4) contain spaces.

You could use this

```bash
cut -c 1-13,84- cmd.txt > cmd2.txt
```

or this:

```bash
awk  '{print substr($0,1,12) " " substr($0,84)}' cmd.txt > cmd2.txt
```

The big problem with those solutions, that the length of each column!

But, it's possible to determine the lengths:

Awk script file `columns.awk`:

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    COLS[++NB_COLS] = "Port"
    COLS[++NB_COLS] = "Protocol"
    COLS[++NB_COLS] = "Type"
    COLS[++NB_COLS] = "Board Name"
    COLS[++NB_COLS] = "FQBN"
    COLS[++NB_COLS] = "Core"
}
NR == 1 {
    for (COL in COLS) {
        START_COL[COL] = index($0, COLS[COL])
        if (COL > 1) {
            LEN_COL[COL - 1] = START_COL[COL] - START_COL[COL - 1] - 1
        }
    }
    LEN_COL[NB_COLS]=length($0)
}
{
    print substr($0, START_COL[1], LEN_COL[1]) " " substr($0, START_COL[6], LEN_COL[6])
}
```

With:

```bash
chmod 755 columns.awk
```

Used like:

```bash
./columns.awk cmd.txt > cmd2.txt
```

`cmd2.txt` file content:

```
Port         Core
/dev/ttyACM0 
/dev/ttyACM1 arduino:avr
/dev/ttyAMA0 
/dev/ttyAMA1 
/dev/ttyAMA2 
/dev/ttyAMA3 
/dev/ttyS0   
/dev/ttyUSB0 
/dev/ttyUSB1 
/dev/ttyUSB2 
/dev/ttyUSB3
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using a file. As I do in my edited post?